# how to redirect to a external 404 page python flask

Tags: python, redirect, error-handling, flask

I am trying to redirect my 404 to a  external URL like this:

```py
@app.route('404')
def http_error_handler(error):
    return flask.redirect("http://www.exemple.com/404"), 404
```

but it does not work. I keep getting:

> Not Found
> The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.

Comment: the problem may be the 404 status you are passing alongside the redirect.

Answer (score 36):

You should try something like this:

```
from flask import render_template

@app.errorhandler(404)
def page_not_found(e):
    return render_template('404.html'), 404
```

Source http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/patterns/errorpages/

Comment: I don't have the 404.html file on the same project I need to redirect to another website and still have my 404 status code I already look at the doc many times..

Comment: Well you dont have to actually redirect to a template, do something like this return redirect("http://www.example.com", code=302)

Comment: It just an example to show how to handle the error, then inside you do whatever you want

Comment: Dude, just type 404, it's an example, what do u want, to just copy and paste?

Comment: So you are handing the 404 error but when should be redirected to http://www.exemple.com/404 you are getting this error instead? "Not Found The requested URL", like, some 500 internal server error?

Comment: I'm getting this I already try this "Redirecting... You should be redirected automatically to target URL: exemple.com/404. If not click the link." but it never redirect ....

Comment: Whats actually hilarious is that now (2019), the link above return an actual 404 error page, hehe! the new link link is http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/patterns/errorpages/

Answer (score 6):

You cannot do this - the *user-agent* (in most cases, a browser) looks at the *status code* that is returned to determine what to do.  When you return a 404 status code what you are saying to the user-agent is, "I don't know what this thing is you are requesting" and the user-agent can then:

- Display what you return in the body of the response
- Display its own error message to the end user
- Do some combination of the above two options

`redirect` actually [creates a little HTML response (via werkzeug.exceptions)](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/werkzeug/blob/bf2456f11972f00b0156aa4f9a7f7d2cd7674970/werkzeug/exceptions.py#L115-L146), which normally the end user doesn't see because the user-agent follows the `Location` header when it sees the 302 response.  However, you *override* the status code when you provide your own status code (404).

The fix is to either:

- Remove the status code (at the cost of sending the wrong signal to the end user, potentially)
- *or* Send a 404 with [a `meta:refresh` and / or JavaScript redirect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL_redirection#Refresh_Meta_tag_and_HTTP_refresh_header) (slightly better, still confusing):

  ```
  return redirect("/where-ever"), 404, {"Refresh": "1; url=/where-ever"}
  ```

Answer (score 4):

Try this instead of a route

```
from flask import request
@app.errorhandler(404)
def own_404_page(error):
    pageName =  request.args.get('url')
    print(pageName)
    print(error)
    f = open('erreur404.tpl')
    return f.read()
```

Comment: Nearly every line in your example is very non-pythonic. You suggest to use CamelCase in place of snake_case, your reading a file template instead of return a response, and pointlessly printing the page name. Just my opinion.

Comment: what is request?

Comment: @JohnD probably found out by now but that's referring to `flask.request`