# How to redirect to default 404 page with flask-restful

Tags: python, redirect, flask, flask-restful

My resource is shown at bottom and it is hooked to `/jobs/` using

`api.add_resource(JobAPI, '/jobs/<int:job_id>')`

I also have a custom 404 page. If the requested `job_id` doesn't exist, how can I redirect to the custom 404 page? I tried to use `abort(404)` but it only shows some JSON message

> {
>       "message": "The requested URL was not found on the server.  If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again. You
>   have requested this URI [/jobs/1] but did you mean /jobs/
>   ?" }

I also tried to `return redirect()` but since `marshal_with` has been used, it doesn't redirect but insists on returning a job instance.

```
  class JobAPI(Resource):                                                            
      """                                                                            
      Simple job                                                                     
      """                                                                            
      @marshal_with(job_fields)                                                      
      def get(self, job_id):                                                         
          job = Job.query.get(job_id)                                                
          if job is None:                                                            
              abort(404)                                                             
              # flash('Job does not exist.')                                         
              # return redirect(url_for('home.index'))                               
          return job
```

Comment: Did you tried to use [error handlers](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/patterns/errorpages/)? [Here the same problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29516093/how-to-redirect-to-a-external-404-page-python-flask)

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `ERROR_404_HELP=False` in your flask application configuration, worked for me.
[Flask-Restful Doc link here](http://flask-restful.readthedocs.io/en/0.3.6/quickstart.html?highlight=ERROR_404_HELP)

Answer (score 0):

As correctly mentioned in the previous answer set the flask object configuration ERROR_404_HELP to False in the file where you have created your flask object.

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['ERROR_404_HELP'] = False
```